# Проверка полей формы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Чтоб проверить правильность заполнения формы регистрации мне посоветовали использовать библиотеку JQuery. Посмотрел в интернете, и там в основном написано про jQuery Simple Validation Plugin. Но это какой то дополнительный плагин. А для обычного JQuery возможна проверка без подключения и установки этой самой валидиции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У плагина Validation есть режим более детальной проверки, скажем так. С возможностью не только проверки полей, но и вывода различных сообщений об ошибках для одного поля.

Да, в jQuery достаточно много различных фильтров для проверки значений полей. Без плагинов проверки как обычно регулярные выражения и т.д. Ну, я думаю далее Вы уже знаете...

Comment: Следовательно можно и без валидации обойтись?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду плагин Validation?

Comment: Да. Можно ли обойтись без него?

Comment: да, конечно.